# How to use the 2nd default IP address on Burst.net VPS?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ip, vps

I just bought a VPS from Burstnet. The VPS comes with two static IPs but I dont know how to use the second IP.

When I check the IP address, it always shows the first IP. How can I let it show the second IP?

I am on Ubuntu 10.10.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure the 2nd IP is assigned to one of the available physical interfaces like `eth0`/`eth1` or to a virtual interface like `eth0:0`.

About the IP usage, this largely depends on how you want to use it. For example, you can point your DNS record to the 2nd IP if you want to host some web service using this IP. So, accessing your service by name will direct you through the configured IP.

Comment: Which file should I look at? `/etc/network/interfaces`?

Comment: @SusanMayer: Yes, this file contains the network interfaces configuration under Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Run

```
ifconfig -a
```

and you should see the second interface, probably called "eth1". To use it you wll need to assign it an IP, either through DHCP or a static configuration.